# Tal condition string contains

Tags: pyramid, template-tal, chameleon

Trying to change table data based on conditions.

```
<td tal:condition="string.stringname != '-shadow'"><strong>Stuff</strong></td>
<td tal:condition="string.stringname == '-shadow'"><em>Stuff</em></td>
```

string.stringname may have `-shadow` at the very end of the string, and it may not. I'm trying to get tal to display either table data based on whether one or the other is true. The page will need to display both cases, if both cases are met of course. `tal:condition` doesnt seem to be able to search if a string contains something, only if something is explicitly true or false.

Comment: Presumably this is with the Chameleon template engine?

Comment: Yes indeed. Apologies I missed the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) to test if a string ends with a given substring:

```
<td tal:condition="not string.stringname.endswith('-shadow')"><strong>Stuff</strong></td>
<td tal:condition="string.stringname.endswith('-shadow')"><em>Stuff</em></td>
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. I'm curious though, and this may come up. Is there a way to do this with text in the middle of the string? I know python can with `in`, but I don't believe you can with this template. Example, `otherstring.stringname` might end with `-shadow1396378908` the numbers denoting unix timestamp. No way to know what the timestamp is, but I may need to use `tal:condition` the same way, and it won't end with `-shadow`. Thoughts?

Comment: Just use `in`; these are Python expressions, so just use Python: `'-shadow' not in string.stringname` and `'-shadow' in string.stringname`

Comment: Hm. I tried that (or some variation) and it didn't seem to work. I suppose if it arises I'll play around with it. Thanks again, I was googling for a good hour and a half >.<